# UITableView alphabetical index with large JSON data

Tags: ios, json, objective-c, database, uitableview

I have a table that loads in data from a webservice that returns a bunch of JSON data. I load more data when the user scrolls down as the database I am querying holds quite a bit of data.

The question I have is - will it be feasible to implement the right side alphabetical listing on such a table and how could this be done? It is definitely possible if I load in ALL the data and then sort them locally, populate the index and cache the data for every other time. But what if this is going to be 10K rows of data or more. Maybe load this data on application first launch is one option.

So in terms of performance and usability, does anyone have any recommendations of what is possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you should download all data to make those indexes, it would decrease refreshing time and might cause memory problems.

But if you think that indexes could make a good difference than you can add some features to your server API. I would add either a different API call like `get_indexes`. Or even I would add `POST` parameter `get_indexes` which adds an array of indexes to any call which has this parameter set.

And you should be ready to handle cases when user taps on indexes without any downloaded data or when user just stresses out your app making fast index scrolling up and down.

Comment: Yes so eventually I ended up having the API return different sections and not doing the index after all - thanks

Answer (score 1):

First see how big the data download is. If the server can gzip the data, it may be surprisingly small - JSON zips very well because of the duplicated keys.

If it's too big, I would recommend modifying the server if possible to let you specify a starting letter. That way, if the user hits the "W" in the index you should be able to request all items that begin with "W".

It would also be helpful to get a total record count from the server so you can know how many rows are in the table ahead of time. I would also return a "loading..." string for each unknown row until the actual data comes down.

Comment: Thanks @erics, I actually have not considered getting the data compressed. I think that might potentially work! Also getting the total record is a great idea.

Comment: I think (but am not certain) that NSURLConnection will automatically expand gzip data via HTTP now, so it's just up to the server to send it that way.